# Extract table from web

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

need to extract data from `<a href="#">Data</a>` from `url` below.
Any clue how to extract this table into DataFrames?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dgOdlUEq6_V55OHZCxz5BG_0uoghJTeA6f83br5peNs/pub?range=A1:D70&gid=1&output=html#'

r = requests.get(url)
html_doc = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, features='html.parser')

#print(soup.prettify())
print(soup.title)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to start of with a multi-dimensional list, then port it to a DataFrame, that way we aren't assuming sizes. The *"Data"* hyperlink references the div id=0, so we select all elements in that, then parse each column in each row into a an list array (in which I call *elements*) that gets appended to a full list array (which I call *fullelements*) and reset for each new row.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dgOdlUEq6_V55OHZCxz5BG_0uoghJTeA6f83br5peNs/pub?range=A1:D70&gid=1&output=html#'

r = requests.get(url)
html_doc = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, features='html.parser')

#print(soup.prettify())
print(soup.title.text)
datadiv=soup.find("div", {"id": "0"})
elementsfull =[]
row=0
for tr in datadiv.findAll("tr"):
    elements=[]
    column=0
    for td in tr.findAll("td"):
        if(td.text!=''):
            elements.append(td.text)
            column+=1
            #print('column: ', column)   

    elementsfull.append(elements)        
    #print('row: ', row)        
    row+=1

mydf = pd.DataFrame(data=elementsfull)
print(mydf)
```

I tested this code and checked it against the table, so I guarantee it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dgOdlUEq6_V55OHZCxz5BG_0uoghJTeA6f83br5peNs/pub?range=A1:D70&gid=1&output=html#'

r = requests.get(url)
html_doc = r.text
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html_doc, features='html.parser')

table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'subs noBorders evenRows'})
table_rows = soup.find_all('tr')

list1 = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text for tr in td]
    list1.append(row)

df=pd.DataFrame(list1)    
df.columns =  df.iloc[1]
#starting from this point,it's just how you want to clean and slice the data
df = df.iloc[3:263]  #check the data to see if you want to only read these
df.dropna(axis='columns', how='all', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read_html and handle dataframe as required

```
import pandas as pd
results = pd.read_html('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dgOdlUEq6_V55OHZCxz5BG_0uoghJTeA6f83br5peNs/pub?range=A1:D70&gid=1&output=html#')
result = results[0].dropna(how='all')
del result[0]
result.dropna(axis='columns', how='all', inplace=True)
result.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf_8_sig',index = False, header=None)
```